# React and Grunt - Envify NODE_ENV='production' and UglifyJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, gruntjs, reactjs, browserify

I am using **Grunt** to build a React project and I want to have 'dev' and 'prod' flavours. As react docs says:

> To use React in production mode, set the environment variable NODE_ENV to production.
>   A minifier that performs dead-code elimination such as UglifyJS is
>   recommended to completely remove the extra code present in development mode.

I am very new using grunt, browserify and stuff but let's see. First problem I have is with envify, I use it as a transform:

```
browserify: {
  options: {
    transform: ['reactify'],
    extensions: ['.jsx']
  },
  dev:{
    options: {
      watch: true //Uses watchify (faster)
    },
    src: ['js/app.js'],
    dest: 'js/bundle.js'
  },
  /**
   * To use React in production mode, set the environment variable NODE_ENV to production.
   * A minifier that performs dead-code elimination such as UglifyJS is
   * recommended to completely remove the extra code present in development mode.
   **/
  prod: {
    options: {
     transform: ['envify'] //How to set up NOD_ENV='production' ?
    },
    src: ['js/app.js'],
    dest: 'js/bundle.js'
  }
},
```

Ok, doing grunt:dev works just fine. So when running grunt:prod... How can I set NODE_ENV: 'production'? I mean, I know I am passing 'envify' as a transform but... No idea how to use that.

After this, I also have an uglify task:

```
uglify: {
 prod: {
   files: {
     'js/bundle.min.js': ['js/bundle.js']
   }
 }
}
```

So after calling grunt:prod, what it creates is two files (`bundle.js` and `bundle-min.js`). In production I will like to only have `bundle.min.js`. I know I can do:

js/bundle.js': ['js/bundle.js']

But mmm I don't know if there is a way to just rename it to bundle.min.js, I guess so... the problem is that in the html I have:

```
<script src="js/bundle.js"></script>
```

Is there here also a trick to make it accepts either bundle.js or bundle.min.js?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Transforms are local, and well made packages put their transforms in their package.json file.  Unless you're using envify in **your own code**, you don't need to do anything with it.

What you do need is [grunt-env](https://www.npmjs.org/package/grunt-env), or another way to set environmental variables.

Here's an alternative by using package.json:

```
{
  "scripts": {
    "build": "NODE_ENV=development grunt build-dev",
    "dist": "NODE_ENV=production grunt dist"
  }
},
"devDependencies": {
  "grunt": "...",
  "grunt-cli": "..."
}
```

The benefit here is that the person using your package doesn't even need to install grunt globally.  `npm run build` will run `./node_modules/.bin/grunt build-dev` with the correct environmental variable set.

Comment: That's great! Thank you. About the last part of my question, any suggestion?

Comment: I'd always used grunt-env (works great!), but hadn't thought of the scripts in package.json approach. handy tip!

Comment: Have you actually confirmed that this works for React? I don't think React contains any transforms in `package.json`. I'm not sure that what you describe is enough to actually envify React.

Comment: The answer is right. This works for packages that specify `browserify` configuration in their `package.json`. React does that, but some ecosystem projects don't. When in doubt, check :-)

Answer (score 8):

Both John Reilly's and FakeRainBrigand 's answers did not work for me. What worked for me was the following:

**Step 1** - Run this command where your package.json is

```
npm i grunt-env --save-dev
```

**Step 2** - Add the code in "evn:" to your Gruntfile.js within grunt.initConfig like so:

```
grunt.initConfig({

...

env: {
    prod: {
        NODE_ENV: 'production'
    }
},

...

});
```

**Step 3** - Add the grunt task to your Gruntfile.js

```
grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-env');
```

**Step 4** - Call it before browserify like so:

```
grunt.registerTask("default", ["env", "browserify"]);
```

Comment: Perfect - been struggling with this for a while and this solved it for me!

Comment: This was what worked for me too since I wasn't building my bundle using an npm task, but rather running grunt directly.

Answer (score 3):

Just an addition to the great answer by FakeRainBrigand, if you're running on Windows (like me) then you need a subtly different syntax in your `scripts` section:

```
{
  "scripts": {
    "build": "SET NODE_ENV=development&&grunt build-dev",
    "dist": "SET NODE_ENV=production&&grunt dist"
  }
},
"devDependencies": {
  "grunt": "...",
  "grunt-cli": "..."
}
```

Comment: Or you could use https://www.npmjs.com/package/cross-env - so it's runnable on all systems (macOS, Windows, Linux).