# Compiled file with react.js too large

Tags: javascript, reactjs, gruntjs, browserify

I created a module with react.js and jsx. I included lodash as only external library. My compiled file with Grunt and Browserify is 1.1mb and almost 500kb minified. How is this possible and how can I reduce the filesize?

My gruntfile

```
module.exports = {
    dist: {
        options: {
            debug: true,
            transform: [require('grunt-react').browserify]
        },
        src: [ 'src/js/app.js' ],
        dest: 'dist/app.js'
    }
};
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34239559

Comment: use less code. frameworks often sandbag you app before the business logic even hits the engine...

Comment: My source code is less then 20kb. And I only use lodash as external library. So that's not the problem

Comment: You're probably not envifying your build correctly. 1MB doesn't sound too crazy to me, for a _dev_ build. Once you've envified your build and used something like UglifyJS's dead code elimination, you should be well under 500kb minified. See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25751045/react-and-grunt-envify-node-env-production-and-uglifyjs) for example.

Answer (score 5):

The way you import `lodash` can make a huge difference. Out of curiosity, I tried the following (while keeping the rest of my code unchanged):

1) Import **all** of `lodash`

```
import _ from 'lodash';
```

and use it as

```
const attending = _.find(attendees, (o) => o.id === parseInt(userId, 10));
```

Bundle size:

[image]

2) Import **just the functions I need**

```
import find from 'lodash/collection/find';
```

and use it accordingly

```
const attending = find(attendees, (o) => o.id === parseInt(userId, 10));
```

Bundle size:

[image]

That's **0.42 MB** you can save by importing only what you need!